# video playback for edited clips is black and no audio or video

Tags: edit-mode, video

I am editing a montage video for youtube, and I am doing this with many individual clips that I link together. Everything has been going fine as I've done this a few times before already, but I aloaded up my project today, and a few (way too many) of my clips were just completely blacked out on the playback screen. The audio for my files are also gone. If I put the files back into blender, the new ones work, but the old ones just seem to not even exist anymore. I had used transforms on a few of the clips, and I had spent hours on these transformations I can't do them again I put so much hard work into it it would kill me to have to do these transformations again. Why on earth would my clips just stop working? How do I fix these please someone help me.

Comment: EDIT: The clips that have been blacked out are seemingly random. Some I have worked on very recently, and some of them I haven't touched in over a week. I have NO CLUE why this is happening I would appreciate any insight. Any solution at all that doesn't require me to do all that work all over again I need, please and thank you.

Comment: This might help: In the Video Sequencer window select your video clip strip, press N to show the strip settings if you don't have those open already. Select the Strip tab and look under Source to check if the file path still refers to you video clip file.

Comment: Hi. If you need to add more information please use the [edit] link below your question to add it to the question directly. Thanks.

Comment: Are the clips in the same folder as they were before? were they moved or renamed in the OS?